# How to make this ajax checker for multiple fields in the form?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the code below where it validates the form.  How do i make it so i can reuse the code for other fields besides username?

How do i make it so i can have multiple other fields and use the same jquery code for validation?

```
<form name="form" id="form" class="form" action="success.html" 
onsubmit="return validate(this)" method="post">
<label for="username">User Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
// form validation function //
function validate(form) {
var username = form.username.value;
var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/;

if(username == "") {
inlineMsg('username','You must enter your username.',2);
return false;
}
if(!username.match(usernameRegex)) {
inlineMsg('username','You have entered an invalid username.',2);
return false;
}

if(username.length>20){
inlineMsg('username','Username is too long (max 20 char)', 2);
return false;
}


return true;

}


// START OF MESSAGE SCRIPT //

var MSGTIMER = 20;
var MSGSPEED = 5;
var MSGOFFSET = 3;
var MSGHIDE = 3;

// build out the divs, set attributes and call the fade function
function inlineMsg(target,string,autohide) {
var msg;
var msgcontent;
if(!document.getElementById('msg')) {
msg = document.createElement('div');
msg.id = 'msg';
msgcontent = document.createElement('div');
msgcontent.id = 'msgcontent';
document.body.appendChild(msg);
msg.appendChild(msgcontent);
msg.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
msg.style.opacity = 0;
msg.alpha = 0;
} else {
msg = document.getElementById('msg');
msgcontent = document.getElementById('msgcontent');
}
msgcontent.innerHTML = string;
msg.style.display = 'block';
var msgheight = msg.offsetHeight;
var targetdiv = document.getElementById(target);
targetdiv.focus();
var targetheight = targetdiv.offsetHeight;
var targetwidth = targetdiv.offsetWidth;
var topposition = topPosition(targetdiv) - ((msgheight - targetheight) / 2);
var leftposition = leftPosition(targetdiv) + targetwidth + MSGOFFSET;
msg.style.top = topposition + 'px';
msg.style.left = leftposition + 'px';
clearInterval(msg.timer);
msg.timer = setInterval("fadeMsg(1)", MSGTIMER);
if(!autohide) {
autohide = MSGHIDE;  
}
window.setTimeout("hideMsg()", (autohide * 1000));
}

// hide the form alert //
function hideMsg(msg) {
var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
if(!msg.timer) {
msg.timer = setInterval("fadeMsg(0)", MSGTIMER);
}
}

// face the message box //
function fadeMsg(flag) {
if(flag == null) {
flag = 1;
}
var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
var value;
if(flag == 1) {
value = msg.alpha + MSGSPEED;
} else {
value = msg.alpha - MSGSPEED;
}
msg.alpha = value;
msg.style.opacity = (value / 100);
msg.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
if(value >= 99) {
clearInterval(msg.timer);
msg.timer = null;
} else if(value <= 1) {
msg.style.display = "none";
clearInterval(msg.timer);
}
}

// calculate the position of the element in relation to the left 
of the browser //
function leftPosition(target) {
var left = 0;
if(target.offsetParent) {
while(1) {
left += target.offsetLeft;
if(!target.offsetParent) {
break;
}
target = target.offsetParent;
}
} else if(target.x) {
left += target.x;
}
return left;
}
// calculate the position of the element in relation to the 
top of the browser window //
function topPosition(target) {
var top = 0;
if(target.offsetParent) {
while(1) {
top += target.offsetTop;
if(!target.offsetParent) {
break;
  }
  target = target.offsetParent;
}
} else if(target.y) {
top += target.y;
}
return top;
}

// preload the arrow //
if(document.images) {
arrow = new Image(7,80); 
arrow.src = "images/msg_arrow.gif"; 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us about or show the code for the inlineMsg() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plugin I used in the past:
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Take a look in there and it might be good for you. I personally modified it to fit my needs but that's a bit extreme.

You should never have to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Will check it out.